# android - make text away from my toolbar

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar

when I scroll my text forward my toolbar , text mix with my toolbar title , it look bad .

any idea how to fix this issue 
thank you in advance 
[image]

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/noActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#3232ff">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the root layout to be *LinearLayout* and it will work just fine

Comment: your first answer was right , I use linearlayout it work fine

Comment: Ha changing it back so

Comment: thank you , you save my day , I will accept this answer